# Bilingual MS Access problems with OLE server or ActiveX control

Tags: utf-8, activex, arabic, ms-access-2016, ole

Developed English/Arabic MS Access 2016 scoring app. The .accdb file works fine on my windows10-64bit machine. When running the same app. on another machine, the following happened in sequence :

1. An Arabic label caption (set in VBA code) appears as hearts!!!
2. Pressing a form close button (I added it) returns the famous error "A problem occurred while communicating with OLE server or ActiveX control".

In Windows10 language settings -> administrative language settings -> Current system locale (Arabic) I unchecked the option "Beta : Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support' The app ran fine then the strangest thing happened : Another similar MS App developed by me failed the same way!!!
The situation NOW :

- checking the Unicode UTF-8 option first app. works fine, second app. fails
- Unchecking the Unicode UTF-8 option first app. fails , second app.  works fine, and so on
- The accde. file created on the second machine fails on my original developing machine. (Both machines are 100% identical as far as Windows / MS Access / App. settings)
  I did each and every research possible, failed to come up with a reason / solution .... can somebody help?